# How can I find the index of the smallest member of this vector in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, reduce

I have used the following expression to retrieve the index of the smallest number in a vector. However, I  would like to avoid the use of `.indexOf` (for efficiency reasons and maybe numeric precision, although I guess the numbers are implicitly converted to strings).

```
(.indexOf [1 2 3 4 0 5]
  (reduce #(if (< %1 %2) %1 %2) [1 2 3 4 0 5] ))
```

Would it be possible to do it differently using reduce?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
user=> (first (apply min-key second (map-indexed vector [1 2 4 0 5])))
3
```

Comment: Can be slightly simplified by using http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.seq-utils/indexed

Comment: Note that I don't think the above comment is true anymore - the 'indexed' function appears not to exist in Clojure 1.3 on.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest using loop/recur if you want to do this efficiently, perhaps something like the following:

```
(defn min-index [v] 
  (let [length (count v)]
    (loop [minimum (v 0)
           min-index 0
           i 1]
      (if (< i length)
        (let [value (v i)]
          (if (< value minimum)
            (recur value i (inc i))
            (recur minimum min-index (inc i))))
        min-index))))
```

The idea is to iterate across the whole vector, keeping track of the minimum and the index of the minimum value found so far at each point.

Comment: Was there a reason you chose not to make it robust to an empty input? Just brevity, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `reduce`:

```
(def v [1 2 3 4 0 5])

(second (reduce (fn [[curr-min min-idx curr-idx] val]
  (if (< val curr-min)
    [val curr-idx (inc curr-idx)]
    [curr-min min-idx (inc curr-idx)])) [(first v) 0 0] v)) ;; => 4
```

The result of `reduce` is actually a three-element vector consisting of the **minimum value**, its **index**, and an index tracker (which is not important), respectively. And it traverses the collection once.

The initial value provided to `reduce` is basically the first element of the collection.

I know the question is old, but it is here for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @Alex Taggart's answer, using [thread-last macro](https://clojure.org/guides/threading_macros#thread-last):

```
user=> (->> [1 2 4 0 5]
  (map-indexed vector)   ; [[0 1] [1 2] [2 4] [3 0] [4 5]]
  (apply min-key second) ; [3 0]
  first)
3
```